# Specify a default action for git add

Tags: git

`git add` without arguments yields in the following message

> Nothing specified, nothing added.
>   Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?

Most of the time I use `git add -p`. Is there a way to make `git add` default to a specific operation when no arguments are given?

I know I can add a shorter alias to `git add -p` but I’d love to just be able to type `git add`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post suggests that it is not possible to override builtin commands: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538791/2761742

If you want a new alias that acts like `git add` but with a default behavior of `git add -p` you could use something like this (at least on linux):

```
[alias]
        ad = "!f() { if test \"$@\"x == \"\"x ; then git add -p ; else git add $@ ; fi } ; f"
```